# respond_to html and js if remote is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have next code in controller:

```
def show
    respond_to { |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    }
end
```

And I have two views - `show.html.haml` and `show.js.haml`.

I have opened a page in browser and received HTML.

But if I have used `jquery-ujs` and link with `remote: true`, I have received JS.

In documentation written:

> Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client.

But If using jquery-ujs, Accept always `text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript`

How I can receive HTML in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `format: :html` to your `link-to` helper, like this:

```
= link_to "Product", [:admin, @product], format: :html, remote: true
```

But then you need some javascript function, which will handle the callback of this ajax call, and do something with the fetched html

Comment: I'm afraid yes. Is there some problem with using the additional `format: :html`, or the behaviour is different then you expected?

Comment: problem with using the additional `format: :html`. I have written a lot of code. Thank you